# code rurns perfectly but pdf is not downloading in laravel when it it called

Tags: php, laravel, dompdf, laravel-nova

I am using dompdf and trying to download pdf . i am trying to call the method for downloading the pdf from my **nova action** file and it also shows no error but the PDF is not downloading .

Any quick suggestion will be helpfull

my action file

DownloadOrganizationReportPDF.php :

```
    <?php

namespace App\Nova\Actions;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Laravel\Nova\Actions\Action;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields;

class DownloadOrganizationReportPDF extends Action
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, Queueable;

    /**
     * Perform the action on the given models.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Fields\ActionFields  $fields
     * @param  \Illuminate\Support\Collection  $models
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
         $invoiceController = new \App\Http\Controllers\InvoiceController();
        return $invoiceController->makePDF();


    }

    /**
     * Get the fields available on the action.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields()
    {
        return [];
    }
}
```

my controller

InvoiceController.php :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use PDF;

class InvoiceController extends Controller
{
    public function makePDF()
    {

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('report');
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
    }
}
```

my view file

report.blade.php :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>check</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you got blank page?

Comment: no i am getting nova's success message that action ran successfully , but pdf is not downloading